# Do carrier proteins constantly open and close or do they only work when a substance binds to them?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, cell-membrane

1. What causes carrier proteins to change shape ?
2. Do they need energy to change shape? If that is true, how are they involved in Facilitated diffusion ?
3. By changing shape, do we always mean opens from one side and closes from another ? (they all work by changing shape right ?)
4. once they transport a molecule from inside to outside, do they return to their original shape instantly or do they need to transport a substance from inside to the outside to return to their original shape ?
5. and finally, are all co-transport proteins carrier proteins ?